# VMware - CentOS 6.5 Static IP Addresses

Tags: linux, networking, centos-6, centos6.5

I installed CentOS 6.5 On VMware Workstation With a static IP Addresses but I'm not able to use Internet connection!!

I applied all the steps performed in this post (From the official CentOS Website): https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6 but no change.

So, here is my configuration's files :

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=e27d33be-dfc0-425c-a382-d21ed55dd3de
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BOOTPROTO=static
HWADDR=00:0C:29:C9:BE:CF
IPADDR=192.168.1.66
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network**

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=hadoop.opentuto.com
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search opentuto.com
# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

When I ping `192.168.1.1` and `8.8.8.8` from the Centos box, I get these messages :

```
[root@hadoop Desktop]# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.66 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.66 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.66 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
.....

[root@hadoop Desktop]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.66 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.66 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.66 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
.....
```

When I execute ifconfig from the CentOS box, I get this :

```
[root@hadoop Desktop]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:C9:BE:CF  
          inet addr:192.168.1.66  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fec9:becf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29919 (29.2 KiB)  TX bytes:8376 (8.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:37648 (36.7 KiB)  TX bytes:37648 (36.7 KiB)
```

When I ping the VM `ping 192.168.1.1` is `Unreachable`

Ad finally, `arp -a` dont show dont show the static IP addresses of the CentOS box, It show only this :

```
C:\Users\open>arp -a

    Interface : 192.168.1.7 --- 0xd

    Interface : 192.168.56.1 --- 0x14

    Interface : 192.168.80.1 --- 0x16

    Interface : 192.168.42.1 --- 0x17
```

My computer IP Addresses is : 192.168.1.6.
My router IP Adresses : 192.168.1.1.
I'm Using Bridged Network.

*NB : I posted the same question on Stackoverflow, but one user told me, I have to move here because Stackoverflow is only for programming questions.*

Thank you.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 from the Centos box?

Comment: can you show your `ifconfig` output and is the MAC address added to the arp cache on your host machine if you ping the VM? `ping 192.168.1.66` followed by `arp -a` - you should see the 66 IP on the list.

Comment: @medhi  Please [edit] your question to include any additional info, this type of thing is difficult to read in comments.  Seems like the bridging setup on the VMWare side is not working.

Comment: @Paul I edited the post,  You can read it now. Thank you

Comment: as @Paul mentioned, seems you have problems with the bridged networking. please go to the virtual network editor, check your bridged settings. I would try with "Restore Defaults" as I had similar problems with my NATed network and after resetting it and setting up again with desired settings it worked.

Comment: `[root@hadoop Desktop]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=279 ms`
(The Result of the ping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After initial troubleshooting the problem was identified to be VMware Workstation's Network settings. Resetting with "Restore Defaults" in the Virtual Network Editor solved the issue.