# VMware workstation - Internet connection not working on CentOS 6.5

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, bridged, centos6.5

After I configured my VM to use Bridged networking and Installed CentOS on it with a Static IP Addresses, I found my self unable to use Internet connection.

I asked a question about Network Configuration Files on CentOs 6.5, but it seems that the problem is coming from the VM, according to some answers on the Forum.

Have you ever faced a similar problem ? And how did you solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Many people have faced many problems, but one needs more input to give a solution to answer a general question. So the answer to your question here is: "Yes, I have faced such problems. I troubleshooted it and it was resolved". Why are you opening this thread as it looks related to your own question here [VMware - CentOS 6.5 Static IP Addresses](http://superuser.com/questions/1048415/vmware-centos-6-5-static-ip-addresses). There you did a great job with providing useful information. Your last comment shows that ping is working so it looks resolved. There you have the process (the how).

Comment: @Zina but still not able to use internet connection. How that is resolved!!??

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misread your last comment that you are able to ping 8.8.8.8 - what would indicate a working Internet connection as 8.8.8.8 is the IP of Google DNS Servers. Would you care to explain what is not working?

Comment: @Zina When I open the browser and I type any website It doesn't work (Server not found Firefox can't find the server at www.opentuto.com...). The same for pinging google `ping www.google.com` I get  `unknown host`

Comment: if ping 8.8.8.8 works then Internet connection is fine, if ping www.google.com does NOT work than you have a DNS problem (firewall, no nameserver set,...)

Comment: try nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8 or dig www.google.com 8.8.8.8

Comment: @Zina nslookup  result : `Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: www.google.com
Address: 216.58.212.100`

Comment: @Zina dig result : `<<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> www.google.com 8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: YESS I resolved it :) I added `DNS2=192.168.1.1` to my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`. Thank you so much  @Zina

Comment: so you had two different problems. glad you have resolved them.

Comment: You helped me a lot @Zina . You are doing a great job. I'm happy with your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After identifying that the Internet connection was working it was setting up the correct DNS setting (see OP's comments).